# How to select between different Resource files in .Net?

Tags: c#, resources

I'm trying to figure out how to choose between two different (identically designed) Resources files in code. All of the examples I can find online are in reference to having different language specific Resource files which are chosen based on setting the culture value. That won't work for my probelm.

This is a web service which returns an image from one of several different image repository systems. Depending on a parameter passed in to the method, the service will need to access an image repository system in order to pull the image being requested. When accessing the image repository, there are a bunch of "magic string" GUID values that represent different IDs for various lookups in that system. One of the purposes of this service is to hide all of that complexity from the user. Rather than hard-code these GUIDs into the code, I have put them into a Resources file.

The problem is this: Each different image repository system has the same set of magic string IDs that need to be used. However, the actual GUID values for these magic strings are different depending on which repository you are connecting to. For example, there is a value called "GroupIDPrompt" which might be "8a48f393642a753f0164418b670a7cdf" on one system, but "63aa28c3637b58680163b25f7e5a5d96" on a different system. In code, I'd like to refer to this value as just "Resources.GroupIDPrompt" or something similar, but I need to be able to set which Resources file will be used at runtime, based on what the consumer of the service sent me.

Normally, I might solve a problem like this by using an interface, and instantiating a specific implementation of that interface based on the request. There are two reasons that doesn't work here - #1, Resource code files are generated automatically, and if I edit them to make them inherit from an interface, this will get broken everytime the file is regenerated. #2, All resource values are created to be static members, and interfaces aren't allowed to declare static members.

I could throw the Resources files away and instead build a class to expose these values, but that means re-introducing magic hard-coded strings to my code. That isn't too terrible, I suppose, but the Resource editor is really quite handy for managing and editing these values.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use some other data format for this such as a plain XML or JSON file? You could still expose a `Resources.GroupIDPrompt` property which gets the correct GUID based on consumer input.

Comment: @DanWilson Having the values compiled into the binary will simplify access and speed up processing over using external files. I could avoid that by adding the files as embedded resources, but gets me right back to my original question and now requires the file to be parsed. Also, having the values compiled in guarantees at compile time that all sets have all of the required values. If a future developer adds a new one, the code will fail to compile if they missed one. In an external file, we won't find that out until the service tried to use a missing value.